# $f'(x)=-\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{(f(x))^2+(g(x))^2}}$ and $g'(x)=1-\frac{g(x)}{\sqrt{(f(x))^2+(g(x))^2}}$ then evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $$f'(x)=-\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{(f(x))^2+(g(x))^2}}\forall x\in R$$ and
$$g'(x)=1-\frac{g(x)}{\sqrt{(f(x))^2+(g(x))^2}}\forall x\in R$$

Also, $g(0)=0,f(0)=10$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$,

then find value of $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$

**My Attempt:**

I could do till here only $(f'(x))^2+(g'(x)-1)^2=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: compute the derivative of $\sqrt{f(x)^2 + g(x)^2}$.

> You find that it equals
>  $$-1 + \frac{g(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)^2 + g(x)^2}} = -g'(x) \,.$$
>  Therefore $\sqrt{f(x)^2 + g(x)^2} = -g(x) + C$. Necessarily $C = 10$. Solve for $g(x)$:
>  $$f(x)^2 = -20g(x) + 100$$
>  so the limit of $g(x)$ is $5$.

Comment: wait it seems -g(x) not g(x), so $-g(x)+C$ ?

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Hi. I am not getting what you are getting. Let $y=\sqrt{(f(x))^2+(g(x))^2}$. So, $y'=\frac{2f(x)f'(x)+2g(x)g'(x)}{2\sqrt{(f(x))^2+(g(x))^2}}=-(f'(x))^2+(1-g'(x))g'(x)=-(f'(x))^2-(g'(x))^2+g'(x)$

Comment: @aarbee Try plugging in $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ in the RHS, rather than plugging in $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Meaning, write the RHS in terms of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.